# Implementing a binary operation for the null object pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, null

Today I needed to implement a class for representing rectangular regions with some binary operations such as merging or intersection.

```
public class Region
{
    // Properties, such as top-left and bottom-right corner ...
    // Ctors ...

    public Region Merge(Region other)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public Region Insersect(Region other)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Intersecting two instances of `Region` unfortunately does not always have a useful result. So my next step was to implement the notion of a `NullRegion`. It is no problem to implement the `NullRegion` itself. However, this would require `Region` to check against `NullRegion`, as those binary operations are commutative and the order should not matter. (i.e. `nullRegion.Intersect(nonNullRegion)`should yield the same result as `nonNullRegion.Intersect(nullRegion)`, which is a `NullRegion`)

The first solution I can think of is to move the implementation of those methods into a seperate class. That way, I only the new class needs to know the `NullRegion`.

```
public class Region
{
    // Properties, such as top-left and bottom-right corner ...
    // Ctors ...

    public virtual bool IsNull { get { return false; } }

    public Region Merge(Region other)
    {
        return RegionMethods.Merge(this, other);
    }

    public Region Intersect(Region other)
    {
        return RegionMethods.Intersect(this, other);
    }

    private class NullRegion
    {
        public override bool IsNull { get { return true; } }
    }

    private static class RegionMethods
    {
        public static Region Merge(Region Region, Region otherRegion)
        {
            // ...
        }

        public static Region Intersect(Region Region, Region otherRegion)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to tackle the problem? What would be my alternatives?

Comment: Maybe I'm just having a hard time following because the implementation is missing, but how come you need a `NullArea` at all? Isn't the intersection of two non-overlapping rectangles just a 0x0 `Area` and not a "lack" of an `Area`? This could mean it's just a problem of `Area` != `RectangleCoordinates` and the need for different representations of each.

Comment: Probably the name is not as clear as it should be. The mere area itself is not important, but the coordinates (top-left corner and bottom-right corner) are. I will rename it to `Region`.

Comment: In my domain, a `NullRegion` is a region not having an area and not having any coordinates. Probably the best example is the intersection of two non-intersecting `Region`s. Users of my class should always be able to check if the given `Region` is a `NullRegion` by calling `region.IsNull`. The coordinates do not really matter, possibly one should even throw an `InvalidOperationException` when trying to access the coordinates of the `NullRegion`, as it does not have defined coordinates. However, users should still be able to perform reasonable computations with the `NullRegion`, such as merging.

Comment: To describe it in a more mathematical way: `Region`s are made up of points and the `NullRegion` is the `Region` containing no points at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of a `NullRegion`, shouldn't be done by a separate class, but by a static property of the same class.
If you overide `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` you can just compare the objects to `Region.NullRegion` like

```
public class Region
{
    private static readonly Region nullRegion = new Region();

    private Region()
    {
        Left = 0;
        Top = 0;
        Width = 0;
        Height = 0;
    }
    public Region(Point point, Size size)
    {
        Left = point.X;
        Top = point.Y;
        Width = size.Width;
        Height = size.Height;
    }
    public static Region NullRegion
    {
        get
        {
            return nullRegion;
        }

    }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public Region Merge(Region other)
    {
        if (this == Region.NullRegion || other == Region.NullRegion)
        {
            return Region.NullRegion;
        }
        // default Merge() implementation here
    }
    public Region Intersects(Region other)
    {
        if (this == Region.NullRegion || other == Region.NullRegion)
        {
            return Region.NullRegion;
        }
        // default Intersects() implementation here

    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        //Implementation of your Equals() here
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //Implementation of your GetHashCode() here
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is almost exactly how I solved it in the end, aside from the properties and the immutability of my `Region`s. I added an `IsNull`-property, so my `NullRegion`-check reads like `this.IsNull` or even just `IsNull`. And just to mention it: in my domain merging the `NullRegion` with another region will return the latter one.